# loop of AIC criterion for optimal model selection

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

i have a xlsx file (data.xlsx) with 20 columns. The first column contains the dependent variable (Y) and all the others the independent ones (X1,X2,X3,...,X19). I want to create a loop that calculates the AIC for all possible combinations of Xi's with Y and prints the results. I have the following code that do not include the loop.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
data<-read_excel("data.xlsx")
data
lm1 <- lm(Y ~ . , data = data) 
AIC(lm1) # calculate the AIC value for one model
Y <- data[,1]
Y
X <- data[,-1]
X
```

How can i create a loop to calculate the AIC of all combinations? Can somenone help me?

Comment: I would use a package like `MuMIn`.

Comment: `lm2 <- step(lm1); AIC(lm2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be a lot of possible combinations (524,477 if I calculated correctly). If your goal is to find the best model you should try using the `stepAIC` function from the MASS package with directions = both.